# csv python questions

Tags: python, csv

i am opening a csv file like this:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(open("book1.csv", "rb"))
for row in reader:
    print row
```

how can i replace the value in column 3 with its `log` and then save the result into a new csv?

Comment: What have you tried?  Do you know how to create a new file?  Have you tried creating a new file with the changes in it?  Post that code, also, please.

Comment: how about you read documentation and tutorial?

Comment: It's been 31 minutes since the first question.  Of course, it should be obvious how we can help I__ write code.

Comment: This is why R is a much better tool than Python for this purpose. In R, it'd just be

data$V3 <- log(data$V3)

Comment: Sorry for this offtopic. I__ summary: 622 questions, 6 answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
>>> input = "1,2,3\n4,5,6\n7,8,9".splitlines()
>>> reader=csv.reader(input)
>>> for row in reader:
...     row[2] = log(float(row[2]))
...     print ','.join(map(str,row))
...
1,2,1.09861228867
4,5,1.79175946923
7,8,2.19722457734
```

Answer (score 1):

These links might help:

http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.writer

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=array

Each row being returned by `reader` is an array.  Arrays in Python are 0 based (So to access the third entry in a row, you would use `my_array[2]`)

That **should** help you on your way.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the context manager **WITH** statement for files - cleaner, less code, obviates **file.close()** statements.

e.g.

```
import csv
import math
with open('book1.csv', 'rb') as f1,open('book2.csv', 'wb') as f2:
    reader = csv.reader(f1)
    writer = csv.writer(f2)
    for row in reader:
        row[2] = str(math.log(float(row[2])))
        writer.writerow(row)
```